# PHP | What does 'use function function_name;' (where function is a PHP built-in function) do?

Tags: php, function, methods, require, keyword

I've bumped into some PHP code which uses the `use` keyword slighty different than what I've seen before.
I saw it in the [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com) framework source code actually.

```
use function array_pop;    // --> confusion :/
use function dirname;      // --> confusion :/
use function file_exists;  // --> confusion :/
use function sprintf;      // --> confusion :/
use function is_readable;  // --> confusion :/
use function is_writable;  // --> confusion :/
```

The [**source code**](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/4.x/Slim/Routing/RouteCollector.php#L24-L29) from is line `24` to `29`.

I do know that the keyword `use` is for **including classes**

```
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface; // --> class
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface; // --> class
```

Or for **adding outer scope variables in functions' closure**

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$prefix = uniqid();

$array = array_map(function ($elem) use ($prefix) {  // -> here the use keyword is clear
    return $prefix . $elem;
}, $array);
```

But the `use` keyword in this case declared on top of the script and in front of functions is really strange, besides they all are **built-in function**?!.

### Question

- **What does use function [built-in-function-name]; do in PHP (PHP "^7.4 || ^8.0")?**

Comment: Check out NameSpaces in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: It is to indicate tha you ascually use built in function, not for example \MyVendor\Project\dirname

Comment: Ahh I see, basically to avoid name collision?  But what would happen if I have `\MyVendor\Project\dirname` and `use function dirname;` ?

Comment: import one with alias

Comment: @PeterM yes true makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @PeterM how about putting it as an answer?

Comment: I am gonna speculate that the likely reasons are stylistic and maybe a wee bit of a performance bump.

Comment: @David performance bump? How would improve performance?

Comment: @FedericoBaù just speculating that maybe the compiler likes it.

Comment: I started seeing this about two years ago, and I think it was related to (either directly or indirectly), this [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/use_global_elements) and [discussion](https://externals.io/message/107953), which includes talk of performance as it relates to opcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok is actually pretty easy, the main issue was, that I did not read properly the documentation or I just miss the part, is true though that the `use` keyword is widely used in PHP, besides with different functionality all together.
Either way, **thanks for whom helped me figured out in the comment section[ ([@riggsfolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly), [@peterm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5444623/peterm), [@eis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365237/eis), [@david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867903/david))** of the question and after good reading and testing I'd decided to post the answer my self.

---

### Quick Answer

The `use function [some_function]` is a [`namespace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) which defines / import that function for a particular place, this place being the namespaced section givin possibility to have same named function from different namespace and even  [modifying the name with alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing), both for functions and namespace all together.

**It can be a user defined namespace, or the global namespace**

In this case, calling built-in function this way merely for style / clarity but also may **[PHP Performance Tip: Use fully-qualified function calls when working with namespaces](https://www.bram.us/2020/04/18/php-performance-tip-use-fully-qualified-function-calls-when-working-with-namespaces/)**

---

### Detailed Answer

So the `use`keyword is scattered with these functionalities:

- **Namespace** Import / Include: **Modules (as packages), Classes, Traits, Interfaces, functions, constants**
- Use outer scope of variables in **closure functions**
- Inject traits in Classes.

So my question refers to the first point **Import / Include** (Functions).

The namespace are somehow more evident when using Classes, as soon as a namespace is declared on the script, that script becomes relative to that namespace and not the global anymore. Hence, if you then call any classes that aren't defined in the very same script without specify the namespace, will result in error, [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php#language.namespaces.fallback):

```
<?php    

    namespace A\B\C;
    class Exception extends \Exception
    {
    }
    
    $a = new Exception('hi'); // $a is an object of class A\B\C\Exception
    $b = new \Exception('hi'); // $b is an object of class Exception
    
    $c = new ArrayObject; // fatal error, class A\B\C\ArrayObject not found

?>
```

But even more clear example is this:

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;
$b = new Exception('hi'); // Uncaught Error: Class "A\B\C\Exception"
```

By removing the namespace, it goes back to the global context

```
<?php
$b = new Exception('hi'); // no errors..
```

---

However, this is not happening with the `const` and `functions`, that's why is little less obvious and will silently fall back to the outer scope if not found.

> For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist.

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;

const E_ERROR = 45;
function strlen($str)
{
    return \strlen($str) - 1;
}

echo E_ERROR, "\n"; // prints "45"
echo INI_ALL, "\n"; // prints "7" - falls back to global INI_ALL

echo strlen('hi'), "\n"; // prints "1"
if (is_array('hi')) { // prints "is not array"
    echo "is array\n";
} else {
    echo "is not array\n";
}
?>
```

Finally, for some example regarding my question:
**File functions.php**
<?php

```
namespace MyApp\Package;

//use function var_dump;
function var_dump($var)
{
    echo '[', __NAMESPACE__, '] don\'t wnat to do that...<br/>';
}
function explode($separator, $some_string)
{
    echo '[', __NAMESPACE__, '] opps, bomb failed :(...<br/>';
}
```

**File index.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;
require_once 'functions.php';

use MyApp\Package; // Demostrate that we can 'import' the entire package namespace
use function MyApp\Package\var_dump; // Import the function only

class A
{
    public static function say() {
        $a = "a";
        $b = "b";
        $data = ['a' => $a, 'b' => $b];
        echo var_dump($data); // --> Calling the namespaced function
    }
    public static function sayReal()
    {
        $a = "a";
        $b = "b";
        $data = ['a' => $a, 'b' => $b];
        echo \var_dump($data); // -> with \ we make the lookup fully-qualified and falls back to global
    }
    public static function explodeBadBomb($bomb="something to explode")
    {
        Package\explode(" ",$bomb); // -> demostrate that we can namespaced in withing blocks and statements
    }
    public static function explodeGooodBomb($bomb="something to explode")
    {
        echo print_r(\explode(" ", $bomb)); // again calling the built-in
    }
}
A::say();               // [MyApp\Package] don't wnat to do that...
A::sayReal();           // array(2) { ["a"]=> string(1) "a" ["b"]=> string(1) "b" }
A::explodeBadBomb();    // MyApp\Package] opps, bomb failed :(...
A::explodeGooodBomb();  // Array ( [0] => something [1] => to [2] => explode )
```

### Documentation

- [Using namespaces: fallback to global function/constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php#language.namespaces.fallback)
- [Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)
- [FAQ: things you need to know about namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.full)

**More on performance improvement**

- [PHP RFC: declare(function_and_const_lookup='global')](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/use_global_elements)
- [[RFC] "use global functions/consts" statement](https://externals.io/message/107953)

### Related StackOverflow Questions / Answers

- [Should a PHP interface have a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092266/should-a-php-interface-have-a-namespace)
- [How and where should I use the keyword "use" in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136277/how-and-where-should-i-use-the-keyword-use-in-php)
- [In PHP, what is a closure and why does it use the "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier)
- [Use keyword in functions - PHP [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320521/use-keyword-in-functions-php)